# gateway-to-gateway timeout

Tags: firewall, gateway, symantec

How do I make a backup of all settings on my symantec gateway 320, my company needs a new one due to having to reset all the time because one of our tunnels is contstantly timing out.
Company has no contract with Symantec. So they are not allowing me to speak with technician. Any ideas why I would have to reset the firewall multiple times ona daily basis in order to keep consistent connectivity to another gateway-to-gateway tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

Is the SGS 320 connected to a UPS that provides quality power?  If not, that could be an issue.  Have seen this numerous times with similar dcevices.

As mentioned by LapTop006, heat can be an issue.  Have seen the SGS stacked with a modem and a switch or some other combo and heat gets to one or several devices.

My SGS 420 has been rock solid for about a year but it is not stacked and it has power from a UPS.

What do the SGS logs show?  Any additional clues?

Is the connection made using an ADSL modem or other device?  Same power and heat issues would apply

Failing that:

To back up a Symantec Gateway Security 300/400 series appliances configuration

Turn off the appliance, turn DIP switches 1 and 2 to the on (up) position, and turn on the appliance. 
Copy the symcftpw.exe utility from the CD-ROM to a folder on your hard drive. 
Double-click the symcftpw icon. 
In the Server IP text box, type the IP address of the appliance. 
The default IP address of the appliance is 192.168.0.1. 
In the Local File text box, type a file name for the backup file. 
Click Get. 
When the Get process finishes, turn off the appliance, turn DIP switches 1 and 2 to the off (down) position, and turn on the appliance.

Symantec recommends that you store backup files on removable media and in a safe location.

To restore a Symantec Gateway Security 300/400 series appliance configuration 
Turn off the appliance, turn DIP switches 1 and 2 to the on (up) position, and turn on the appliance. 
Copy the symcftpw.exe utility from the CD to a folder on your hard drive. 
Double-click the symcftpw icon. 
In the Server IP text box, type the IP address of the appliance.
The default IP address of the appliance is 192.168.0.1. 
In the Local File text box, type a file name for the backup file. 
Click Put. 
When the Get process finishes, turn off the appliance, turn DIP switches 1 and 2 to the off (down) position, and turn on the appliance.

Answer (score 0):

Heat issues is by far the most likely, followed by OS bugs.